# How to load csv files in a tensorflow program?

Tags: python, csv, image-processing, tensorflow, conv-neural-network

I am working on a deep neural network by following the tensorflow tutorial on convolutional neural nets. But the dataset i have is in the form of csv files. I have 4 csv files 2 for training(xtrain.csv and ytrain.csv) and 2 for testing(xtest.csv and ytest.csv). xtrain.csv and xtest.csv contain the inputs with 1280 rows and 4096 columns and 320 rows and 4096 columns respectively. Here each row represents an image of dimension 1x4096. Therefore the input layer will have 4096 neurons. now the ytrain.csv and ytest.csv contain the output with 32 rows and 1280 columns and 32 rows 320 columns respectively where each column represents the output for a particular image in the form of a one hot vector. so there are going to be 32 neurons in the output layer. Can someone please guide me on how to load the csv files for input and output(label) into my program?

Comment: Brief answer: I would use Python's "csv" library to read the data. To feed tho data into Tensorflow, you should convert the csv data into numpy arrays. You can then feed those arrays as inputs to Tensorflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tensorflow has a function below that seems like would do it.

```
tf.decode_csv(records, record_defaults, field_delim=None, name=None)
```

You can use this to load your data into a tensor. From there you just need to convert the tensor to the correct shape.

```
imgs = tf.decode_csv(csv_file, tf.float32)
imgs = tf.reshape(imgs,shape=(num_of_imgs,64,64))
```

keep in mind that tf.decode_csv each column will be a tensor. You can do something similar for the labels.